# Webpack 5 and Storybook 6 integration throws an error in DefinePlugin.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook

Working on **Webpack 5** and **Storybook** integration in our **React** apps' repository. Mainly upgrading from **Webpack v4** to **v5** because its support has been announced [here in this blog post](https://storybook.js.org/blog/storybook-for-webpack-5/) officially. Following the suggested [full instructions](https://gist.github.com/shilman/8856ea1786dcd247139b47b270912324#upgrade).

With the below mentioned setup I get the following error message on the console:

```
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished
10% building 0/1 entries 0/0 dependencies 0/0 modulesℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: 
/opt/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/DefinePlugin.js:549
           const oldVersion = compilation.valueCacheVersions.get(name);                                                                                           
                                                             ^
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at /opt/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/DefinePlugin.js:549:57
```

Basically the error is coming from the marked line in [`/node_modules/webpack/lib/DefinePlugin.js`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/49a11ce49d9518333e5f1194c6c506e909c5bc26/lib/DefinePlugin.js#L565) once running for the first time `npm run storybook`.

#### Technical details:

See `package.json` related `devDependencies`:

```json
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/addon-options": "^5.3.21",
"@storybook/addon-toolbars": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/addon-viewport": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/addons": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/react": "^6.2.3",
"@storybook/storybook-deployer": "^2.8.7",
"@storybook/theming": "^6.2.3",
// ...
"@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.3",
"html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "^2.0.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
"terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
// ...
"webpack": "^5.31.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^4.1.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
"webpack-filter-warnings-plugin": "^1.2.1",
"webpack-isomorphic-tools": "^4.0.0"
// ...
"crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
"stream-browserify": "^3.0.0"
```

Also the `webpack.config.js` content:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    alias: {
      '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    },
    fallback: {
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      KEY: 'value'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
          },
        },
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      }
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
}
```

And the `main.ts` setup for **Storybook**:

```
import { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react/types'

module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  stories: [
    '../../src/stories/**/*.example.@(ts|tsx)'
  ],
  logLevel: 'debug',
  reactOptions: {
    fastRefresh: true,
  },
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-controls',
    '@storybook/addon-options',
    '@storybook/addon-toolbars',
    '@storybook/addon-viewport',
  ],
  webpackFinal: config => {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: { ...config.resolve },
      module: { ...config.module }
    }
  },
} as StorybookConfig
```

#### Questions:

I have tried to downgrade **webpack** till the version of [`"webpack": "^5.25.1"`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v5.25.1) where the issue is not existing but the Storybook pages are not loading anymore. Also I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375674/upgrade-to-webpack-5-breaking-storybook-5/66825007#66825007) here which seems unrelated.

- Any idea where should I take a look to progress further?
- Any configuration what's missing maybe regarding this `compilation.valueCacheVersions.get(name)` line from **webpack**?

I couldn't find anything related in the documentation. If more information needed, let me know in the comment section, thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We had the same issue.

First, you will need to install `@storybook/builder-webpack5@next`.

Then you have to upgrade every @storybook dependency to version `^6.3.0-alpha.6` using this command:

```
npx sb@next upgrade --prerelease
```

Upgrade also `dotenv-webpack` to `^7.0.2`.

Another small fix we had to do was to add this line in the storybook `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
config.resolve.fallback = {
  http: false,
}
```

Full instructions can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/shilman/8856ea1786dcd247139b47b270912324)

Comment: Thanks for your help, this seems to be working fine!

Comment: Thank You! You've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I had to run `npm i --save-dev html-webpack-plugin` and `npm i --save-dev dotenv-webpack`

Comment: Could you explain the commands for yarn users too?

Answer (score 9):

Update storybook components to their latest stable version,
**no need for alphas** (atm stable is 6.2.9)

You could follow the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/shilman/8856ea1786dcd247139b47b270912324#upgrade):

```
npm i -D @storybook/builder-webpack5@next
npm i -D dotenv-webpack
```

Then update your .storybook/main.js:

```
 module.exports = {
   core: {
     builder: "webpack5",
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

There's chaos with Storybook's own dependency on Webpack v.4 at the moment. Try pinning the version of your storybook packages at 6.2.3 and adding the latest `dotenv-webpack` as your dev dependency. Obviously, perform the usual dance of deleting the `node_modules` folder in case there are some conflicting dependencies.

Links to relevant issues:

- [description of the problem and recommendation about dotenv-webpack](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14403)
- [an issue that caused Storybook maintainers to revert their fix used in v.6.2.4](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14497)

Comment: Thanks for your help! The links are pretty useful, I got the explanation why `dotenv-webpack` is required to install here from there.